# enabledwhen without using property tester class

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp, plugin.xml

I have a tree created using `TreeViewer`. I want to disable a menu item say "Expand All" when user right clicks on the last tree item (i.e., tree item does not have a child). Using `PropertyTester` i am able to achieve this. 
plugin.xml code:

```
<enabledWhen>
   <with
     variable="selection">
     <iterate
            ifEmpty="false">
            <instanceof
                    value="com.xxx.automation.touchstone.model.GUIObject">
            </instanceof>
     </iterate>
     <test
            forcePluginActivation="true"
            property="com.xxx.automation.touchstone.testers.GUIObjects.canExpandAll"
            value="true">
     </test>
   </with>
</enabledWhen>
```

I want to know if we can achieve the same without using property tester class. I mean using `ContentProvider`'s `hasChildren` method within the plugin xml .

Thoughts

Comment: Can you use a different class for the leaf nodes? You could then use the `instanceof` test.